# How to find certificate in X509 store without breaking on a certificate update

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

In a web service application I have this function to load a certificate by its Thumbprint:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var t = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
    if (t.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Certificate collection is empty");
    }
    X509Certificate2 cert = t[0];
    store.Close();
    return cert;
}
```

string thumbprint is a setting in the web.config file.

As I understand the Thumbprint is calculated as a HASH form the entire certificate and therefore will change if the certificate is updated.

From [X509FindType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I can see that there are around 15 different types of FindBy{..} is one better than the other?

What will be the best practice for finding the certificate in a way that my settings will survive a certificate update without the need to update web.config after the system administrator has updated the certificate?

Comment: Finding by friendly name would do.

Answer (score 2):

What certificate update do you have in mind?

You see a certificate is signed by CA that issued this certificate. Any change to this certificate will result in breaking of the signature and therefore making the certificate untrusted.

Therefore the thumbprint of the certificate will never change. When you reissue the certificate (even if it will be on the same private key) it will have different thumbprint because it will be a new certificate (with new serial number, new validation intervall etc.).

In my opinion you don't need to change anything. A thumbprint is pretty unique way to identify a certificate. When it will be time to reissue the certificate you will schedule a maintenance, edit your config to set thumbprint of new certificate and restart your application to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique enough subject name to search by (`FindBySubjectName`), that should be stable across cert renewals, so you won't have to update your code or config every time you renew a cert, which can be infrequent enough that everyone tends to forget all the pieces involved. If you put both the search type and search value in a config system that's at least as easy to maintain as the cert renewal, you might be able to have devops staff (non-developers), or end users take care of it.